# use callback_before_insert method twice

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

When use the `callback_before_insert` twice, implement one and the other are not implemented

**First use**

```
$crud->field_type('state', 'invisible');
$crud->add_fields('state', 'delete_time');
$crud->callback_before_insert(array($this, 'Invisible_callback'));

function Invisible_callback($post_array) {
  $post_array['state'] = 1;
  return $post_array;
}
```

**Second use**

```
$crud->field_type('delete_time', 'invisible');
$crud->add_fields('state', 'delete_time');
$crud->callback_before_insert(array($this, 'Invisible_deleteTime_callback'));

function Invisible_deleteTime_callback($post_array) {
  $post_array['delete_time'] = 2000;      
  return $post_array;
}
```

callback that inside the first use is implemented, but the callback that inside the second use does not implemented when use the `callback_before_insert` twice.

I must use `callback_before_insert` twice.

**Now, how to solve this problem ?**

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you please give some information for the reason that you want to use twice the callback_before_insert? For me it seems that just once is fine. Are you using two different methods? 
e.g. ````function method1() {//first use}```` 
````function method2() {//second use}```` ?

Answer (score 1):

You CANNOT use `callback_before_insert` twice with one `crud` object. If you really want to use it twice, either:

1. create new crud object (whoever this will give you a new form and NOT the data from same form)
2. use just 1 callback_before_insert call, and inside the callback method you do needed checking to see which state of form you are managing.
3. use argument list or parameters from the url to determine the state you are in. Then you use if/else and call the callback_before_insert you want.

So it depends upon your scenario...